# AngularJS: Detecting performance problems on mobile

Tags: angularjs

Are there any tools that can assist in detecting performance issues with AngularJS on mobile?
I can seem some obvious ones such as a massive ng-repeat I have, but I am looking to find the issues that aren't so obvious.

Any recommendations on how to detect problems areas?

Answer (score 0):

Not mobile specific, but [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) is a Chrome extension that can help diagnose performance problems within Angular. The "performance" tab will show you all of the watch expressions, how long each take, and the percentage of time for the request.